# F5 APM HTTP auth agent fails with curl timeout

Tags: f5-big-ip

I've been having some annoying and persistent trouble with F5 APM module.

I'm trying to setup SSLVPN with 2FA in F5 BIG-IP version 15.1. We are using partitions and route domains and all of the things described here have been configured in non-default route domain (say **5** in this case) and non-Common partition (say **Example**). This route domain **5** is the default route domain in **Example** partition.

I'm able to configure SSLVPN login using localdb, but when I try to add 2FA via http auth agent to an external mail/sms server, I get curl timeouts in APM module:

> HTTP module: authentication with 'username' failed: Curl perform
> failed: Timeout was reached  (28)

I've setup an AAA HTTP server that points to a virtual server in the same partition. That virtual server has a redirect iRule that redirects the request to an external https endpoint. If I try to call that virtual server with curl using the correct route domain (with *rdexec 5 curl ...*), everything works beautifully.

However, when trying to login to the SSLVPN and triggering the HTTP auth agent call, APM fails with the aforementioned error. I've stumbled upon the following F5 articles:

https://my.f5.com/manage/s/article/K71206522

> The BIG-IP APM system always uses route domain 0 to connect to the RSA
> SecurID servers for authentication, regardless of the configured route
> domain. When the Agent Host IP address for the SecurID AAA server is
> configured in a route domain other than 0, the BIG-IP APM system
> cannot connect to the RSA SecurID servers.

https://my.f5.com/manage/s/article/K20465715

> 891465
>
> Add support for Route Domains with both AAA HTTP and the E-mail Agent
>
> Route domains are only supported for AAA servers that have the
> option to select a pool. There is no option to select a pool for an
> HTTP AAA server. Additionally, the SMTP configuration required to
> support the Email Agent does not have an option to select a pool.

So am I on the right track when I'm assuming that APM is trying to call the virtual server from Common partition (even though stuff is defined in Example partition) , but fails because it cannot find a route there? There is no default gw in the common partition.